# Multiple bootstrap modals make browsers freeze

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I want to pop up multiple bootstrap modals on the same page to make my web application look like a desktop OS. I also use `jQuery UI` draggable to make modals movable.

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/F27SL/4/

This fiddle is a simpler version of what I want to implement.
The problem is that when I pop up the third modal, my browser (Chrome) freezes.
I have tested the fiddle with IE and FF, FF works fine but IE also freezes as Chrome.

**Is it a bug of bootstrap?**

Comment: [This](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues) is probably a better place to ask your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering myself.

I found a couple of issues dealing with this problem from GitHub.

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5431

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4781

So the answer I found is

> bootstrap doesn't support multiple simultaneous modals (it's a poor ui choice). thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a "hide" to the class when using multiple modals, this works great for me in all browsers: ...

Answer (score 1):

adding a "hide" class works!! so if two modals are stacked :

```
$("#first").addClass('hide');
$("#second").removeClass('hide');
$("#second").modal('show');
```

Works!